# Checking if something was malloced

Tags: c, malloc

Given a pointer to some variable.. is there a way to check whether it was statically or dynamically allocated??

Comment: Out of curiosity, what motivates the desire to do this?

Comment: im making a method that will basically get rid of a struct.  
it has a data member which is a pointer to something that may or may not be malloced.. depending on which one, i would like to free it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting from your comment:

> im making a method that will basically get rid of a struct. it has a data member which is a pointer to something that may or may not be malloced.. depending on which one, i would like to free it

The correct way is to add *another* member to the struct: a pointer to a deallocation function.

It is not just static versus dynamic allocation. There are *several* possible allocators, of which `malloc()` is just one.

On Unix-like systems, it could be:

- A static variable
- On the stack
- On the stack but dynamically allocated (i.e. `alloca()`)
- On the heap, allocated with `malloc()`
- On the heap, allocated with `new`
- On the heap, in the middle of an array allocated with `new[]`
- On the heap, within a struct allocated with `malloc()`
- On the heap, within a base class of an object allocated with `new`
- Allocated with `mmap`
- Allocated with a custom allocator
- Many more options, including several combinations and variations of the above

On Windows, you also have several runtimes, `LocalAlloc`, `GlobalAlloc`, `HeapAlloc` (with several heaps which you can create easily), and so on.

You must always release memory with the correct release function for the allocator you used. So, either the part of the program responsible for allocating the memory should also free the memory, or you must pass the correct release function (or a wrapper around it) to the code which will free the memory.

You can also avoid the whole issue by either requiring the pointer to always be allocated with a specific allocator or by providing the allocator yourself (in the form of a function to allocate the memory and possibly a function to release it). If you provide the allocator yourself, you can even use tricks (like tagged pointers) to allow one to also use static allocation (but I will not go into the details of this approach here).

[Raymond Chen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Chen) has a blog post about it (Windows-centric, but the concepts are the same everywhere): [Allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060915-04/?p=29723)

Answer (score 2):

The [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library does this all over the place. You may be able to check how they do it. In general you probably shouldn't need to do this in the first place though...

Answer (score 2):

Since the heap, the stack, and the static data area generally occupy different ranges of memory, it is possible with intimate knowledge of the process memory map, to look at the address and determine which allocation area it is in. This technique is both architecture and compiler specific, so it makes porting your code more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Most libc malloc implementations work by storing a header before each returned memory block which has fields (to be used by the free() call) which has information about the size of the block, as well as a 'magic' value. This magic value is to protect against the user accidently deleting a pointer which wasn't alloc'd (or freeing a block which was overwritten by the user). It's very system specific so you'd have to look at the implementation of your libc library to see exactly what magic value was there.

Once you know that, you move the given pointer back to point at header and then check it for the magic value.

Comment: This suggestion is interesting, but not a good solution to the problem: `malloc()` implementations typically only do this in debug mode, accessing memory before the pointer might have undefined behavior and the magic value could be there by coincidence. Even with a specific allocator in debug mode, you could not be certain that the pointer can be safely passed to `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you hook into malloc() itself, like the malloc debuggers do, using LD_PRELOAD or something? If so, you could keep a table of all the allocated pointers and use that. Otherwise, I'm not sure. Is there a way to get at malloc's bookkeeping information?

Answer (score 0):

Not as a standard feature.
A debug version of your malloc library might have some function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare its address to something you know to be static, and say it's malloced only if it's far away, if you know the scope it should be coming from, but if its scope is unknown, you can't really trust that.

Answer (score -1):

1.) Obtain a map file for the code u have.

2.) The underlying process/hardware target platform should have a memory map file which typically indicates - starting address of memory(stack, heap, global0, size of that block, read-write attributes of that memory block.

3.) After getting the address of the object(pointer variable) from the mao file in 1.) try to see which block that address falls into. u might get some idea.

=AD