# Identify buffer allocated with malloc()

Tags: c, posix, c99

Is there any way to identify if a buffer was allocated by 'malloc'? like a function with the following signature:

```
bool is_malloced(void *buf);
```

Does such a mechanism exist in posix?

Comment: `bool is_malloced(void *buf) { free(buf); return true; }` ;) Seriously, I know of no such thing.

Comment: No, but you could write your own allocator that could support this.  But why do you think you need such a function?

Comment: I actually don't *need* such a function, I was just curious...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/276612/1202636

Comment: Your best bet is to replace `malloc` with your own, using a library preloading mechanism or some other, and wrap the POSIX malloc call in your own implementation, adding flagging a pointer as "malloced" in some sort of a map. The problem is there is no portable way of either overriding malloc (there is `malloc_hook` in GNU C) or linking to another `malloc`.

Comment: @TJD just malloc/free wrapper is enough for that, wrapper functions that will add / remove ptr's to allocated chunks in own dynamic or static table (hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Neither C11 nor POSIX provide any such mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

mmm  if you are a serious person, you could actually do:

```
Hash   *hsh;   /* global hash already initialized. */
void *custom_malloc(size_t size)
{
     void  *ptr;

     ptr = malloc(size);

    hash_add(hsh, ptr);
  return ptr;
}

/* tester */

_Bool malloced(void *ptr)
{
      if(hash_retrieve(hsh, ptr))
           return TRUE;
      return FALSE;
}
```

of course doing such thing is madness, but indeed you can.

Comment: It is madness. This was a thought experiment. It isn't going into real code.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to emulate such a functinality would be to wrap `malloc()` in a custom function which:

- allocates a buffer which is e.g. 4 bytes bigger
- stores some magic number (32 bit) at the beginning of the allocated block
- increments a pointer by 4 bytes before returning it to the caller

Given a pointer one can check if it is `malloc`'ed by looking for the magic number.

Of course, it is not perfect:

- the magic number can be there by accident. Setting it to null in a wrapped `free()` call can help. XOR-ing it with the pointer, etc. can also make it more reliable. Still, it's a heuristic.
- on architectures with memory protection you can trigger page fault when checking pointer which was *not* malloc'ed.

With all the drawbacks, it's still a useful technique, I've used it a few times when debugging some memory corruption in embedded systems.

If we are about to replace `malloc()` with some wrapper, we could as well build a linked list of allocated blocks. Much more reliable, but also more complex.