# Find out whether a pointer is pointing at the stack, heap or program text?

Tags: c, pointers

Is there a way to find out whether a pointer is pointing at a location in:

- the stack
- the heap
- or the program (and if so, which section e.g. elf .text)?

Also, can this be done portably (Linux 64/32 bit, OSX and Windows 7+)?

**follow up:**

I'm not trying to find out if something has been malloc'd.

I want to efficiently distinguish void* pointers to functions in the program from void* pointers to data on the stack or heap.

This is for a language runtime written in C, not a "normal" C program.

This answer has been the most useful so far: [Checking if something was malloced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276612/checking-if-something-was-malloced/276626#276626)

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276612/checking-if-something-was-malloced).

Comment: On Windows, you can use WinDbg's `!address` extension to determine this for you.  I don't know about *nix-based operating systems.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot do what you want in a portable way, because the C language standard does not specify the stack, program area, and heap as distinct areas.  Their location can depend on the processor architecture, the operating system, the loader, the linker, and the compiler.  Trying to guess where a pointer is pointing is breaking the abstraction provided by C, so you probably you shouldn't be doing that.

Nevertheless, there are ways to write code that will make a correct guess for a specific environment.  You do that by examining the addresses of existing objects, and looking for patterns.  Consider the following program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void
function()
{
    int stack2;

    printf("stack2:  %15p\n", &stack2);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int stack;
    void *heap = malloc(1);
    void *heap2 = malloc(1);

    printf("program: %15p\n", main);
    printf("heap:    %15p\n", heap);
    printf("heap2:   %15p\n", heap2);
    printf("stack:   %15p\n", &stack);
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

By examining its output you can see a pattern, such as the following on x64 Linux.

```
program:        0x400504
heap:          0x1675010
heap2:         0x1675030
stack:    0x7fff282c783c
stack2:   0x7fff6ae37afc
```

From the above you can determine that (probably) the heap grows up from 0x1675010, anything below it is program code (or static data, which you didn't mention), and that the stack grows in an unpredictable manner (probably due to stack randomization) around a very large address, like 0x7fff282c783c.

Compare this with the output under 32-bit Intel Linux:

```
program:       0x804842f
heap:          0x804b008
heap2:         0x804b018
stack:        0xbf84ad38
stack2:       0xbf84ad14
```

Microsoft Windows and the 32-bit Microsoft C compiler:

```
program:        01271020
heap:           002E3B00
heap2:          002E3B10
stack:          0024F978
stack2:         0024F964
```

gcc under Windows Cygwin:

```
program:        0040130B
heap:           00A41728
heap2:          00A417A8
stack:          0028FF44
stack2:         0028FF14
```

gcc under Intel 32-bit FreeBSD:

```
program:       0x8048524
heap:          0x804b030
heap2:         0x804b040
stack:        0xbfbffb3c
stack2:       0xbfbffb1c
```

gcc under Intel 64-bit FreeBSD:

```
program:        0x400770
heap:        0x801006058
heap2:       0x801006060
stack:    0x7fffffffdaec
stack2:   0x7fffffffdabc
```

gcc under SPARC-64 FreeBSD:

```
program:        0x100860
heap:         0x40c04098
heap2:        0x40c040a0
stack:     0x7fdffffe9ac
stack2:    0x7fdffffe8dc
```

PowerPC running MacOS X:

```
program:          0x1ed4
heap:           0x100120
heap2:          0x100130
stack:        0xbffffba0
stack2:       0xbffffb38
```

PowerPC running Linux:

```
program:      0x10000514
heap:         0x100c6008
heap2:        0x100c6018
stack:        0xbff45db0
stack2:       0xbff45d88
```

StrongARM running NetBSD:

```
program:          0x1c5c
heap:             0x5030
heap2:            0x5040
stack:        0xefbfdcd0
stack2:       0xefbfdcb4
```

and ARMv6 running Linux:

```
program:          0x842c
heap:           0xb63008
heap2:          0xb63018
stack:        0xbe83eac4
stack2:       0xbe83eaac
```

As you can see the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Under Linux, /proc/self/maps gives me all the info I need.

Comment: Did you somehow forget the line of code for creating `heap2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the location generally speaking of the stack and heap, though how large it is will be another story...

```
void *heap_locations;
void *stack_location;

void determine_locations (int any_int) {
   free(heap_location = malloc(248));
   stack_location = &any_int;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  determine_locations(argc);
      .
      .
      .
  return 0;
}
```

A bit rude and you won't know the expansion direction or size of either for absolute sure unless you are dealing with specified platforms.