# How to tell difference between dynamically allocated char* and static char*

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, free

In the program I am working on I have a struct like

```
typedef struct _mystruct{
    char* my_string;
} mystruct;
```

Most of the time the time my_string is allocated using malloc, so there is a function that calls

```
free(mystructa->my_string);
```

Generally this works, but at some points, my_string is set as a literal

```
my_string = "This is a literal";
```

Is there a way to tell the difference between the two before my call to free()?

Comment: No reliable/portable way that I know of.

Comment: Check out the second answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504588/should-i-free-char-initialized-using-string-literals - "Ideally, malloc() calls and free() calls should appear on the same "design level" (inside the same implementation file for the same module for example), and they should match perfectly: one free() for each malloc()"

Comment: You shouldn't solve your problem from that end. Better to use ownership pattern: every object that is stored in memory (by pointer) should be owned by some part of a program. Buffers inside structs fields are usually owned by that structs, so 1) you should always assign dynamically allocated buffers to struct fields (never static strings) and 2) you should always free memory when struct is disposed.

Comment: This question has detailed answer about how objects are stored in memory and why this task is not solvable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360620/find-out-whether-a-pointer-is-pointing-at-the-stack-heap-or-program-text

Comment: i would always strdup the string so that I own the string I am encapsulating. THen if the caller passes a local, const, static all work, even if they pass heap string and later free it

Comment: It seems like my best solution is to make a copy of any string that gets set so that its always the same. Thanks

Comment: Plus 1 to @rutsky's answer. This shouldn't be an issue. Whatever allocates it should be responsible for deallocating it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to reliably distinguish between a pointer to a literal and a pointer to allocated memory. You will have to roll your own solution. There are two ways to approach this:

1) Set a flag in the `struct` indicating whether the pointer should be freed.

```
typedef struct _mystruct {
    char *my_string;
    int string_was_allocated;
} mystruct;

mystructa.my_string = malloc(count);
mystructa.string_was_allocated = 1;
.
.
if (mystructa.string_was_allocated)
   free(mystructa.my_string);

mystructa.my_string = "This is a literal";
mystructa.string_was_allocated = 0;
```

2) Always dynamically allocate using `strdup`.

```
mystructa.my_string = strdup("This is a literal");
free(mystructa.my_string);
```

Both approaches involve changes to existing code, but I think solution 2 is much more robust, reliable and maintainable.

Answer (score -3):

Dynamic memory and static memory go to separate places: stack and heap

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

char aString[] = "this is a string";

printf("the string is located at %x \n", &aString);


char * pString = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
strcpy(pString, "this is a dynamic string");

printf("the pointer is located at %x \n", &pString);

printf("the dynamic string is located at %x \n\n", &*pString);



return 0;
}

/************* *** **************/

robert@debian:/tmp$ gcc test.c 
robert@debian:/tmp$ ./a.out
the string is located at bfcdbe8f 
the pointer is located at bfcdbe88 
the dynamic string is located at 95a3008
```

Comment: The compiler can put heap and static memory anywhere it wants, so how would you know which is which?